# Get the iterator value while using a for structure in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, replace

I must find a way to get the `item` position when iterating over a list using a `for` structure

```
other_list = ["line1", "line2", "line3", ... , "line125k+"]
#contains 125k+ items from a txtFile.readlines()

list = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
#contains 35 items

dict = {"key1":["value1"], "key2":["value2"], "key3":["value3"]}
#contains 35 items too
```

For each `value` inside my `dict`, i got a `key` that have a correspondent `item` in the `list`.

```
list = ["10", "20", "30"]`
dict = {"19":["value1"], "29":["value2"], "39":["value3"]}
```

the dict's first key, "19", corresponds to the "10" inside the other list..

```
Example:
dict[0] corresponds to list[0]
dict[1] corresponds to list[1]
... and so on.
```

So **i have to get the item position while using a for structure**, so then i can access the correspondent key in the dict, and use the dict's value in a `replace()`

```
#replace tax1 value
for item in list:
    pos_item = item.getPosition() # pos_item = getIteratorValue()
    #how can i assign the dict value to a variable?
    dict_value = dict[pos_item][value]
    #use one variable to search and the other as a replacement
    other_list[pos_item].replace("0,00", dict_value)
```

Comment: I think it's not possible to get the index in a foreach loop because of the iterator model. The only thing you could do is set a variable to 0 before the loop and increment it every single run...

Comment: Dictionaries can't be indexed via integers (at least the way you are thinking of it) and their ordering is arbitrary. If you are counting on the order of your dictionary for your code to work you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: dicts have no order so your logic if flawed

Comment: Since dictionaries are not ordered you can not compare its item's position with a list elements!

Comment: hmmm... interesting. so if i sort(dict) i'll be able to work with it my data that way?

Comment: No, dicitonaries can't be sorted.

Comment: use OrderedDict, from collections import OrderedDict

Comment: Based on what you want to do you have 2 choice, at first use a [`OrderdDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of a `dict` or sort your dict items and work with the sorted result which is not a dictionary anymore and is a list!

Comment: You could use `enumerate()`, to find out the current position in the iteration . Obviously, using index won't allow to get dict's items

Comment: @Pardoido, if you are going to be relying on an order. use an OrderedDict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *three* issues here, not one. In Python (and most other languages), dictionaries aren't sorted, and `replace` returns a new string. They *have no order*. In order to get around this, you can use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and do something like:

```
# The dictionary.
dct = OrderedDict([('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2')]
for pos_item, (item, dict_values) in enumerate(zip(lst, dct.values())):
   dict_value = dict_values[value]
   other_list[pos_item] = other_list[pos_item].replace('0,00', dict_value)
```

Look into [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Also notice that I renamed `dict` to `dct` and `list` to `lst`, as [`dict` and `list` builtin functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict). In addition, there may be a bug in your code, as you are never actually using `item`; I'm not sure what it's purpose in your code was.

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpfull:

```
list = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]

for i in xrange(len(list)): # len(list) returns length of the list
    print(list[i])
```

Comment: `xrange` is Python 2-only.

Comment: There is a `python-2.7` tag in this question ;-)